# Display occurrence of each letter in a string?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("type the sentence you want to find the letters of");
    String sentence = s.nextLine();

    getLetters(sentence);

}

public static void getLetters(String sentence) {
    int count;
    char ch[] = sentence.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(ch[i]);
    }

}
```

I am trying to display the occurrence of each letter (letter only) in a sentence, and I am lost. I have converted the string into a char array, but I am now lost.

For instance, if I typed the sentence: "Hello, how are you?"
The result would be:

```
Occurrence of h: 1
Occurrence of e: 2
Occurrence of l: 2
Occurrence of o: 3
etc..
```

I know I need to utilize my int count, but I am not sure how to do that. Our professor is having us use this:

```
    c[26];
    c[ch - 'a']++;
```

And I'm not sure where to use those for this little project.

Edit: Update

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("type the sentence you want to find the letters of");
    String sentence = s.nextLine();

    getLetters(sentence);

}

public static void getLetters(String sentence) {
    sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
    int count[];

    char ch[] = sentence.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(ch[i]);
    }

    char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    System.out.println();


}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you try Hash Map?

Comment: If the professor is telling you to create a counter array `c` with a capacity of 26, and since he is using `ch - 'a'` to determine the letter index, then you have to assume that only lower case letters should be used.  In this case, the count of `h` should be two: `Hello -> hello`.

Comment: @IanMc Based on the statement of expected output, it seems the problem is to count only lowercase basic latin letters. In any case, more or correct words in the question title, functions names and variable names would say.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` to keep track. The key is a unique character, and the integer counts the number of times you see it.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class J {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string = "aaaabbbccd";

    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = frequency(string);

    System.out.println(map);
  }

  public static HashMap<Character, Integer> frequency(String string) {
    int length = string.length();
    char c;

    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    // loop thru string
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      c = string.charAt(i);

      // If u have already seen that character,
      // Increment its count
      if (map.containsKey(c)) {
        map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);

      // otherwise this is the first time u
      // have seen it, so set count to 1
      } else {

        map.put(c, 1);
      }
    }

    return map;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{a=4, b=3, c=2, d=1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see reason to use HashMap here. HashMaps are used to map some values into places in memory for faster access, using HashFunction. In this case he will have same, or very similar thing with array and this mapping function that is given to him(ch-'a') . Also, for someone who is doing this, it is maybe too soon for HashMap.

Your problem is that you haven't understood idea.
Letters in java have values (You can check ASCII table). You have 26 letters in alphabet, first one is 'a' and last is 'z'. So you want to have array of 26 elements. Every time when you have 'a' into your string, you want to increment element in place 0 in array, when you come into 'b' you want to increment element in place 1.... when you come to 'z' element 25. So, in fact with (ch-'a') you map your letter in place in array where is count of its ocurrence.

You take string, do .toLowerCase() case on it, pass it once to count letters, then print what you found.

Comment: You are correct; I was not looking for HashMap. I found your answer very useful. I have converted my string to lowercase, created an alphabet array, but am stuck on how to count for each letter. This is what I have so far (in main)

Comment: You again missed point...

You have array occurrence of 26 int . Initial all elements will be 0. Every time you take char from string you do occurrence  [ch-'a']++.

Comment: Hint: `ch - 'a'` is the distance on the character code number line from 'a' to ch. (On the other hand, while obviously in conflict with the instruction, an alphabet array is a much more general and readable solution.)